# Routing not working after Reactjs deployment on subdirectory

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created a simple landing page using ReactJS on local host, it is working perfectly on http://localhost:3000. then I wanted to catch some marketing parameters, and I did so using  and  and it is working too, however when deploying it, I am getting a blank page when using the parameters.

App.js

```
     <Switch>
          <Route path="/" children={<Normal />} />
      </Switch>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/:cn/:cid" children={<Markdata />} />
      </Switch>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

package.json

```
....
"name": "muslimsgate",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
....
```

.env file

```
/* /index.html 200
```